# RPC Exception After Login

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, gwt, rpc

I have a login project and I control session concurrency. This works fine.(When I call a RPC at second session, it expires.) And redirect login page. But when I want to login on the same login page, `The call failed on the server; see server log for details` is shown in the browser and I have an exception in eclipse like:

```
SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
javax.servlet.ServletException: Content-Length must be specified
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils.readContentAsUtf8(RPCServletUtils.java:131)
    at ...
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you have more details about how are you implementing the control of session concurrency? Is there any filter involved?

Comment: I control concurrency in applicationContext-security.xml like; <session-management >
     <concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login.jsp?error=19"/>
  </session-management>

Comment: And i have a filter like this too;                             <intercept-url pattern="/*.rpc**" access="hasRole('ROLE_LOGGED_USER')" />